# Unexpected status_code from RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing specs for an API. But the response is coming back with a `:created` status when it should be `:unprocessable_entity`.

#### announcements_controller

```
  def update
    head :unprocessable_entity unless announcement
    if annnouncement.update(announcement_params)
      render json: annoucement, status: :ok
    else
      render_unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def announcement
    Announcement.find(params[id])
  end
```

#### announcements_controller_spec

```
it 'fails when announcement does not exists' do
  data = {
    id: 999_999,
    announcement: {
      body: ''
    }
  }.to_json
  post "/api/announcements/#{property.slug}", params: data, headers: headers
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
end
```

#### failure response

```
  1) Api::AnnouncementsController#update fails when announcement does not exists
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
       expected the response to have status code :unprocessable_entity (422) but it was :created (201)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `post` instead of `put`. Because of that the request is routed to `#create` controller action no to `#update` as you want to.

Btw you write:

```
Announcement.find(params[id])
```

there's a colon missing:

```
Announcement.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it but now the status code is 404

Comment: I don't know how you defined routes, but in the default setting, `params[:id]` is passed in URL. You should replace `"/api/announcements/#{property.slug}"` with `"/api/announcements/#{data[:id]}"`